# Jumping to function in Vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I have ctags and I would jump to functions by placing my curson to a function and pressing ctrl ]. However, I find this sometimes to be inconvenient.

For instance, if my cursor is nowhere near a function I want to jump to, then it would be frustrating.

Is there a command in ctags or vim to just automatically jump to a function by typing its name and pressing a button? It would be way better if it was fuzzy and predicts the function for you. So for instance, if I want to go to a function called `process_input()`, then I would type out that function and press `g` or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:tag <identifier>` command is equivalent to `Ctrl-]` when the cursor is over <identifier>. See

```
:help CTRL-]
```

So you can type

```
:tag process_input
```

to jump to that function's tag. Further, the `:tag` command uses tab completion, so you can instead type

```
:tag pro<Tab>
```

and Vim will complete as much of that name as it can. Hit <Tab> again and Vim will cycle through the matches. If you prefer to see a list of possible matches, you can set the 'wildmode` option to something else, e.g.,

```
:set wildmode=longest,list
```

See

```
:help 'wildmode'
```

Comment: Also, `:tag /inp<Tab>` uses regexp completion instead of the default whole-word completion for when you only remember part of a name or when too many symbols share the same prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can jump to a specific known tag with the `:tag` command. For example:

```
:tag process_input
```